# How to stop getting suggested post from un-liked pages in news feeds in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'm seeing posts from un-liked pages of Facebook as suggested post with "like page" link along its side. How could I stop getting this in my news feeds list?

BTW, I'm able to restrict specific pages to post this type of news in my feeds, but not as a whole. Any one know how to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily block all "suggested posts" / "suggested pages" and "related posts" with the safe and free **FB Purity** browser extension. You can get it here: http://www.fbpurity.com/

Comment: Is there any internal entity or configuration to restrict this post other than this extension which act on FB pages itself?

Comment: No facebook don't give you that option, if they did i would have mentioned it.